# Simple html dom функция find в foreach есть в условии а в самои итерации видает referenced method is not found in subject class что сделать?

Tags: php, методы, simple-html-dom

Обращаюсь к функции find в условии foreach - работает; в итерации пишу чтобы углубленно искать в том, что уже нашло - выдает ошибку, что не находит такой метод. 
Заходил в саму библиотеку и там возле функции find писал public, не помогает. Что изменить или добавить?

```
<?php
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$html=new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file(www.example.com);

foreach ($html->find('div.article') as $article){
   echo $article->find('img',0)->src;
}
```

Comment: а вместо `www.example.com` что на самом деле написано? и написано как строка или также без кавычек?

Comment: Если почитать мануал повнимательней http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find можно увидеть что потомков надо искать не методом `find`

Comment: @u_mulder, как раз таки, если внимательно почитать мануал, то можно будет найти примеры с поиском потомков через метод `find()`. Например, во вкладке `Scraping Slashdot!` секции `Quick Start` по вашей же ссылке.

Comment: Переписал код точно так же, ошибка так же высвечивается, но цикл работает и ищет в find. Всем спасибо.